# How to get value from selected array in jquery datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have some code to display data using Datatables and it works fine. How do I get a value from column `id`?

I want to call `window.open()` to print the content of data on the datatables. I expect the data shown to be taken from array `{ "data": "id" }` to passing on `window.open(url)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#load_data').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "data.php",
      "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [{
      "dataId": "id" // I want to get this value
    }, {
      "data": "tgl"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "company"
    }, {
      "data": "status"
    }, {
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='btn-print' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>print</a>",
    }]
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    table.ajax.reload(null, false);
  }, 5000);

  $('#load_data').on('click', 'tbody #btn-print', function() {
    var getID = table.cell(this).data(); //try to catch id value variable
    var url = "print.php?id=" + getID; //i want to pass getID variable to this variable

    window.open(url, "_blank", "dialog=yes,minimizable=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=400,left=400,width=350,height=450");
    console.log(getID);
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that this question isn't about PHP, not does it have anything to do with JSON so I've edited those out for you

Comment: `table.column(0).data()` [is supposed](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data()) to give you what's needed

Comment: Thank you for your reply  @YevgenGorbunkov i have tried  table.column(0).data() it will return all id on that datatable, 
all I want is one id in row which is obtained when I press the print button

Comment: @OscarDoe : `var getID = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().id`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov 
many thanks this worked in my case, the value obtained was as expected :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can get data from the table.

[cell.data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data())

[columns.data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().data())

[rows.data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data())

Here is an example:

```
var ids = table.columns( 0 ).data();   //Get all Ids in to an array
```

Comment: helo @charlie H , yes I have tried this method, but I still can't understand how to select an array with this function, can you give an example to get select spesific id in spesific cell?

Comment: The `ids` array in my example will contain the values of the whole 0th column. If you want the first row, first column: `ids[0]`

Comment: i have tried table.column(0).data() it will return all id on that datatable, all I want is one id in row which is obtained when I press the #btn-print button, but i don't get it how it's work

Comment: Please see my previous comment.

Comment: now it's work with this code from @YevgenGorbunkov var getID = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().id , it seems I have a lot to learn, thank you very much :D